# formatHTMLMesssage() function in React not rendering special characters

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

below is my code:

```
<RaisedButton id="abc" title={formatHTMLMessage({id: 'T_TEXT_TOOL_TITLE'})} className="abcClass" />

T_TEXT_TOOL_TITLE=Some Text to show&#039;
```

When rendering the above component in the UI, the `formatHTMLMessage` function do not render the `&#039;` character as a single quote (`'`), instead it displays `&#039;`.

I tried another function `formatMessage()` as well, but it did not work.
Please find the screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your question seems to be missing the code you're referring to, could you please update it with the relevant code showing exactly what isn't working

Comment: can you please include a screenshot of the output?

Comment: @syed Please find the attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code. Hope it will fix the issue.

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
T_TEXT_TOOL_TITLE=Some Text to show&#039;

<RaisedButton id="abc" title={parser.parseFromString(formatHTMLMessage({id: 'T_TEXT_TOOL_TITLE'}), 'text/html').body.textContent} className="abcClass"/>
```